# How to resize a table in Excel through the JavaScript API?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

In Excel, a table can be resized by dragging its lower-right corner, which makes a table bigger (or smaller) without inserting (or removing) any cells in the worksheet (see “Sizing handle” in Microsoft’s [“Overview of Excel tables”](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)). The equivalent action can be done through the VBA API using [“ListObject.resize”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.resize): “The Resize method allows a ListObject object to be resized over a new range. No cells are inserted or moved.”

How can this be done through the JavaScript API? I’m probably overlooking the obvious, but the [class “Table”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.table?view=excel-js-1.11) at least doesn’t seem to offer a method “resize”.

Comment: As requested in the answer by Raymond Lu, I've added this as a feature request on UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/40686295

Answer (score 0):

Yes, table resize API is currently not available in office JS. but this is in our backlog. Could you please create your request in [uservoice][1] and upvote your request?

Answer (score 0):

Good news, we have created this API and We release `table.resize()` last month together with SAC, now you could try it out. here is the code sample。

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
  // Retrieve the worksheet and a table on that worksheet.
  const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
  const expensesTable = sheet.tables.getItem("ExpensesTable");
  
  // Resize the table.
  expensesTable.resize("A1:D20");
  
  await context.sync();
});
```